Support and usage of HTTPS and SVCB DNS records
I'm attempting to use an HTTPS DNS record to configure the equivalent of a CNAME at the apex of the domain. I'm using GoDaddy, so I created an HTTPS record in alias mode with name of @, priority 0, value of other.example.net.
After this change, assuming my domain is example.com, I was expecting that navigating to https://example.com would load the equivalent of https://other.example.net. However, it's showing the GoDaddy parked landing page.
I then removed the A records which were responsible for the GoDaddy parked page. After that, accessing the domain leads to DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN result.

Is my configuration for HTTPS record type correct?
How widespread is support for this new record type as of April 2024? I have tried Chrome and Firefox and I'm not sure if either is attempting to fetch the HTTPS record type.
If a domain has both A and HTTPS records, does one have a priority over the other?


Before being able to do a proper reply, some comments 1) it would be better to give the actual names involved, and detailed dig outputs 2) as for support see https://arxiv.org/html/2403.15672v1 and 3) probably implementation dependent; right now it seems Safari for example only use HTTPS and ditch any A/AAAA if present at same time.

According to this blog post (dated Aug 8, 2024), HTTPS records in alias mode are supported by Safari, but not by Chromium or Firefox.
